# Change threshold for class prediction in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, rapidminer

How can I change the probability threshold to predict a class as 1 in R.

In rapidminer there is apply threshold operator. How can I achieve the same thing in R?

```
svm_model1 <- svm(x,y,probability = TRUE)
summary(svm_model1)
pred <- predict(svm_model1,x,probability = TRUE)
```

Comment: ifelse(pred>thresh,1,0)?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Can I include this in my model itself?

Comment: Are you looking for somethining like that? : pred[pred<threshold]=0 , 
pred[pred>=threshold]=1

Comment: I did this. This is what I wanted. 

pred.prob <- attr(pred, "probabilities")
th=0.3
pred.probth <- (ifelse(pred.prob[,1]>=0.3,1,0))
confusionMatrix(pred.probth, y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model gives as output a vector of probabilities, only compare the output with a theshold in the case of a binary classification.

Comment: I did this. This is what I wanted. pred.prob <- attr(pred, "probabilities") th=0.3 pred.probth <- (ifelse(pred.prob[,1]>=0.3,1,0)) confusionMatrix(pred.probth, y)